# I want to boot to Epiphany and have a dropdown list of webpages to choose from

Tags: raspbian, python, boot, web-browsers, web-interface

I have a web server with pages that display basically kiosks of different types. I want to create a boot image that will let me select what kiosk this terminal is and then launch its specific page in Epiphany. I figured out how to get Raspbian to boot into epiphany and launch a specific site. But I cant figure out how to launch and give me a prompt so I can select what site to display.

This is my first coding project in python so please specify what language your writing in if you post a script.

I'm open to ideas or suggestions,
Thank you!

Comment: Why not just make a webpage that has a button/link to each of the sites

Comment: I have considered this but I cant think of a way that i can do it without using a mouse.The kiosks are being used as scanner input terminals I'm trying to avoid buying a bunch of mice if at all possible I want to make like a prompt that i can scroll through with up and down arrows hit enter and load.

Comment: I will try this and report back if i can make it tab through the buttons.

Comment: There are ways to navigate a web page w/o a mouse, e.g. (shift) tab.  Worst comes to worst you have to map some keys (easy enough w/ .js).

Comment: @Morgunus: You obviously have some kind of input. A button or keyboard? Heck, it could be set that the first input from a scanner could determine the webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a basic webpage with a button for each site.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
      </head>
      <body>
       <h1>Buttons</h1>
         </div>
           <p>
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default"><a href="url_of_site1">site1</a></button>
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-info"><a href="url_of_site2">site2</a></button>
           </p>
         </div>    
        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

It may be a little easier to see and play with [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vmLr1y10/). I Used bootstrap just to add a little styling quickly. You can tab through the buttons (you can also assign keyboard shortcuts) you just need to make sure that when they receive the focus it is obvious (change color size etc. (watch out for just color though it is not accessible to colorblind users).

Note you could use a dropdown as well but this would be [less usable](http://uxmovement.com/forms/stop-misusing-select-menus/).
Also it is possible for a user to return to this page using the back button. There are ways around this if required.

Comment: This did work to solve the problem I had posted here. But in the adventure to do this I found that I had left myself with a problem that this wouldn't solve. But this was really super helpful so I've made another post for that specific problem I'm sure this will help other people though. I appreciate the help!